# What's the correct way to re-write this nested IF statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary

I have a dictionary with the following structure:

```
{ "123" : {"red" : ['some text', datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 23, 3, 19, 38), status]},
  "456" : {"red" : ['some other text', datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 23, 3, 19, 38), status],
           "blue" : ['some more text', datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 23, 3, 19, 38), status]},
  "789" : {"blue" : ['random text', datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 23, 3, 19, 38), status],
           "yellow" : ['text', datetime.datetime(2009, 8, 23, 3, 19, 38), status]}}
```

Now I have some logic to update this dictionary. It first checks whether an entry already exists in this dictionary and if so whether the sub entry exists and compares the times and updates. If one of those does not exist, it creates a new entry:

```
if example_id in my_directory:
    if color in my_directory[example_id]:
        if time > my_directory[example_id][color][1]:
            my_directory[example_id][color] = [text, time, status]
    else:
        my_directory[example_id] = {color : [text, time, status]}
else:
    my_directory[example_id] = {color : [text, time, status]}
```

Obviously, `time`, `color`, and `status` are passed as already existing variables. What is the proper way to re-write this IF statement to not duplicate the second and third directory update command? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't te build-in update method not work?

Comment: `setdefault()` is your friend:`my_directory.setdefault(example_id, {}).setdefault(color, [text, time, status])`

Comment: Consider using a `collections.defaultdict` instead of vanilla `dict`.

Comment: @VincentBeltman It does work, but this looks odd to me and there must be some way to optimize it so that it doesn't run through so many if-else statements.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Care to provide an example of above using defaultdict. I haven't used it before.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples

Comment: @jonrsharpe, what's the correct way to include defaultdict within another defaultdict?

Comment: You can do e.g. `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, use defaultdict:

```
my_dictionary = collections.defaultdict(
                lambda: collections.defaultdict(
                lambda: (None, datetime.datetime.min, None)))

# populate my_dictionary

_, old_time, _ = my_dictionary[example_id][color]
if time > old_time:
    # NB: tuples make more sense here than lists
    my_directory[example_id][color] = (text, time, status)
```

This will temporarily add a `(None, datetime.datetime.min, None)` tuple to your dictionary, then replace it with the real values.

Comment: Awesomeness, just what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Why not use `my_dictionary[example_id][color][1]` instead of the two dummy variables?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: It's purely a stylistic difference of opinion.  I find magic numbers harder to read than dummy variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `and` operation and remove extra `else`'s  :

```
if example_id in my_directory and color in my_directory[example_id] and time > my_directory[example_id][color][1]:
            my_directory[example_id][color] = [text, time, status]
else:
            my_directory[example_id] = {color : [text, time, status]}
```